# I need to create an iso-8859-1 encoded URI (java.net.URI)

Tags: java, character-encoding, uri

I am using Spring's RestTemplate in order to do a rest call. The RestTemplate takes in an URI (java.net.URI), or a string, which is converted to an URI by Spring's UriTemplate (This one uses UTF-8 as encoding).

I want the URI to be encoded as iso-8859-1, not UTF-8. Is there a way I can do this with java.net.URI (or a way I can do this with Spring's UriTemplate)

As an example, I have the parameter q=Øyvind

The iso-8859-1 encoding (which I want) of this is: `q=%D8yvind`

The UTF-8 encoding of this is: `q=%C3%98yvind`

If I encoded the string first, to iso-8859-1, and then create an URI, it will look like this: `q=%25D8yvind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, using the Spring UriComponentBuilder

```
UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
uri = urlBuilder.build().encode("ISO-8859-1").toUri();
```

If someone has a solution not using the UriCompomentBuilder, I am sure others would appreciate it.